# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith' ao tentar instalar com pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Estou com uma instalação limpa do Python em minha máquina e não consegui instalar pacote algum usando o pip.

Versão do python

```
D:\Users\julio.campos>python --version
Python 3.6.3
```

Versão do pip

```
D:\Users\julio.campos>pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Erro ao tentar instalar

```
D:\Users\julio.campos>pip install glances
Collecting glances
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 589, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 797, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 254, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 66, in create_connection
    if host.startswith('['):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Já tentei reinstalar o pip e o python completamente.